# Playing video in a VideoView using URL forward and a CDN

Tags: android, video, android-videoview

I am trying to play a video file in Android, but get the following exception.

```
    String url = getIntent().getStringExtra("url");
    Log.d(iDomsAndroidApp.TAG, "Url is " + url);
    final VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoplayer_videoView);
    videoView.setVideoPath(url + "?id=" + uniqueAppId.getValue());
```

The response is:

```
D/MediaPlayer﹕ setDataSource IOException happend :
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: https://dominicansinteractive.idoms.org/media/15304/video.mp4?id=13392
            at android.content.ContentResolver.openTypedAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1059)
            at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:913)
            at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:840)
            at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:997)
            at android.widget.VideoView.openVideo(VideoView.java:337)
            at android.widget.VideoView.access$2100(VideoView.java:71)
            at android.widget.VideoView$7.surfaceCreated(VideoView.java:617)
            at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:602)
            at android.view.SurfaceView.access$000(SurfaceView.java:94)
            at android.view.SurfaceView$3.onPreDraw(SurfaceView.java:183)
            at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:888)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2199)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1254)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6630)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:803)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:603)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:573)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:789)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5479)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The problem is I think that this is a https connection, which forwards the request to a CDN (https://idoms-media.o.auroraobjects.eu/15304/1431/encoded.mp4?Expires=1419003882&AWSAccessKeyId=DNC899D1JKFCJFAZLC97&Signature=LhAlZ5%2BobUh0z2KN7VrR5bTthMI%3D)

It works fine in the browser, or on iOS, but I don't know what to do with Android.
Any suggestions of what the problem can be? Is it looking for certain header data or so that is not provided by the forward?

[EDIT:]
It seems that it must be the 'https' of the initial request, as my test server works with the same CDN and seems to work, but that is without the https.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the problem was related to using https, once I removed that it works fine.